# Estou treinando o básico do Javascript e preciso de ajuda numa To-Do List

Tags: javascript, lista

Sou iniciante em JavaScript e tentei fazer uma To-Do List. Basicamente, é um código que cria um item dentro de uma lista não-ordenada usando o texto inserido em um input. Tive sucesso no processo de criar os itens da lista, mas tive a ideia de criar uma função que remove os itens da lista, e foi aí que começou o problema. Tentei fazer com que houvesse um "botão de remover" (entre aspas porque na verdade é uma tag a com href="javascript:funcaoDeRemover()") pra cada item da lista (o qual ao ser clicado removeria o item ao qual está associado e a si mesmo), mas o que acontece é que quando clico em qualquer botão de remover, sempre o último item é removido e os outros botões de remover param de funcionar.

Meu código:

**HTML**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To-Do List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>To-Do List:</h1>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Insira aqui os seus afazeres" id="itemLista">
        <button onclick="addTarefa()">Adicionar tarefa</button>
        <br>
        <ul id="ul">
        </ul>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

**JavaScript**

```js
var itemLista = document.getElementById("ul");
function addTarefa() {
    if (document.getElementById("itemLista").value !== "") {
        var tarefa = document.createElement("li");
        tarefa.innerHTML = document.getElementById("itemLista").value;
        itemLista.appendChild(tarefa);
        document.getElementById("itemLista").value = "";
        var remover = document.createElement("a");
        window.removerTarefa = function () {
            itemLista.removeChild(tarefa);
            itemLista.removeChild(remover);
        }
        remover.innerHTML = "Remover";
        remover.setAttribute("href", "javascript:removerTarefa()");
        itemLista.appendChild(remover);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essa forma que você implementou sua função não é muito ortodoxa, você está declarando a função `removerTarefa` no escopo global dinamicamente e então atribuindo a referencia dessa função para o botão `remover`.

O problema é que só pode existir um símbolo (função ou variável) com determinado nome em um escopo, a cada vez que você invoca a função `addTarefa`, você cria uma nova função `removerTarefa` no escopo global que sobrescreve a `removerTarefa` antiga. Ao invocar `removerTarefa`, você está invocando a última função criada, que irá remover o último item da lista, e se esse item já foi removido, isso é um erro.

Não há a necessidade de declarar essa função para remover o elemento da lista no escopo global, você pode declara-la de forma anônima e atribui-la para propriedade `onclick` do seu elemento como no código abaixo, dessa forma nada é sobrescrito:

```js
var itemLista = document.getElementById("ul");
function addTarefa() {
    if (document.getElementById("itemLista").value !== "") {
        var tarefa = document.createElement("li");
        tarefa.innerHTML = document.getElementById("itemLista").value;
        itemLista.appendChild(tarefa);
        
        var remover = document.createElement("a");
        remover.innerHTML = "Remover";
        remover.setAttribute("href", "javascript:;"); // apenas para parecer um link
        remover.onclick = function() {
            itemLista.removeChild(tarefa);
            itemLista.removeChild(remover);
        }
        itemLista.appendChild(remover);
        
        document.getElementById("itemLista").value = "";
    }
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>To-Do List</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>To-Do List:</h1>
        <br>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Insira aqui os seus afazeres" id="itemLista">
        <button onclick="addTarefa()">Adicionar tarefa</button>
        <br>
        <ul id="ul">
        </ul>
        <script src="script.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Valeu! Quando fui dormir, me toquei desse problema da sobrescrita, e tinha até pensado em uma gambiarra com array pra resolver , mas dessa forma é bem mais fácil.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do @user140828 está certa, ela corrige os problemas do código e adiciona/remove corretamente os itens.

Eu só gostaria de fazer uma sugestão em cima da resposta dele, que seria adicionar o link que remove dentro do próprio elemento `<LI>`. Com isso, temos de remover apenas um elemento, fica mais simples, e não quebra o layout:

```js
var itemLista = document.getElementById("ul");
function addTarefa() {
    if (document.getElementById("itemLista").value !== "") {
        var tarefa = document.createElement("li");
        tarefa.innerHTML = document.getElementById("itemLista").value;
        
        var remover = document.createElement("a");
        remover.innerHTML = "Remover";
        remover.setAttribute("href", "javascript:;"); // apenas para parecer um link
        remover.onclick = function() {
            // remove apenas "tarefa", que é o li
            itemLista.removeChild(tarefa);
        }

        // adiciona o link de remover ao li
        tarefa.appendChild(remover);
        // adiciona o li ao ul
        itemLista.appendChild(tarefa);
        document.getElementById("itemLista").value = "";
    }
}
```

```css
a {
  margin: 0 5px
}
```

```html
<h1>To-Do List:</h1>
<br>
<input type="text" placeholder="Insira aqui os seus afazeres" id="itemLista">
<button onclick="addTarefa()">Adicionar tarefa</button>
<br>
<ul id="ul"></ul>
```

Comment: Vou usar! Queria fazer assim no início, mas fiz de um jeito errado e não tinha percebido, daí desisti de fazer desse jeito.